# My ASP.NET web service on localhost is timing out too quickly

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-services, iis

So here I am, trying to debug a little problem in my ASP.NET web service on localhost, and while I am stepping through it, the darned thing times out.  Here I thought the default timeout value was 20 **minutes**.  But the timeout appears to happen at 30 seconds -- I've timed it twice -- although it was 20 seconds in another timing I did.

I've tried to govern this by setting sessionState timeout to 30, in accordance with what MSDN says about HttpSessionState [HERE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.timeout%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).  With this code:

```
<sessionState
  mode="InProc"
  cookieless="true"
  timeout="30" />
```

in .

MSDN says the value of the timeout is supposed to be in minutes ("Gets and sets the amount of time, in minutes..."), but it doesn't really seem to make any difference what it's set to.  Machine.config does not specify any value, so it should default to 20 minutes.

I am running in IIS 7.5.  I checked the properties of the ASP.NET Session State Mode Settings in IIS, and it is selected as "In process".  I don't know how this affects things, if it does.

So this is a mystery to me.

Comment: I think you are getting the HttpRequest timeout (which effects debugging) and the Session timeouts mixed up :)

Comment: I think you're right!  Yikes, that was a surprise, I thought it was the service throwing the timeout.  It wasn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your client is timing out when calling a web service take a look at-

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.protocols.webclientprotocol.timeout.aspx

Comment: I don't know why I didn't see this myself.  It just looked like the service was throwing the timeout, when it was the client after all.  I have only the excuse that the there was a service timeout set in the client (legacy code that I didn't look at closely enough!).  The timeout was 20 seconds.  I upped this to 10 minutes (600,000 milliseconds) and the problem went away.